# How to change package name - android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

There are many ways to change package name.

I sew several question on stackoverflow but many of developers had error/problem and etc.

what is the best solution to change package name ?

Comment: use this link : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Comment: "but many of developers had error/problem" which one did you try and what error you received? I'd suggest that you make a backup of your project first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personnaly select the package and use `MAJ + F6` (shortcut for refactor -> rename). Enter a new name then validate using the `Refactor` button.

I never had problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [Maloubobola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3580745/maloubobola) answer, please make sure to change the package name inside AndroidManifest.xml file as well under the 'package' tag.